# How to Update getElementsByClassName after doing something?

Tags: javascript

```js
if (document.querySelector(".delete-filter") !== null) {
  let dltbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("delete-filter");
  let contbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("filter-solid");
  for (let i = 0; i < dltbtn.length; i++) {
    dltbtn[i].onclick = function() {
      contbtn[i].remove();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.filter-solid {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #faa938;
  border-radius: 2vw;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  color: #525666;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.filter-solid button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: #525666;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-SfTiTlX6kk+qitfevl/7LibUOeJWlt9rbyDn92a1DqWOw9vWG2MFoays0sgObmWazO5BQPiFucnnEAjpAB+/Sw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
<div>
  <span class="filter-solid"><span> فقط کالاهای تخفیف دار </span> <button class="delete-filter"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></span>
  <span class="filter-solid"><span> از <span>200,000</span> تا <span>1,200,000</span> تومان </span> <button class="delete-filter"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></span>
  <span class="filter-solid"><span> رنگ آبی </span> <button class="delete-filter"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></span>
</div>
```

In above code I want to remove an element after click, but the problem is when I delete elements (**from left**) the count of `dltbtn` and `contbtn` is not updating. I mean when I have 4 elements there is [0, 1, 2, 3] array, so when I delete first element the array should be [0, 1, 2] in order, but it will not be updated. how should I fix this?

Comment: `typeof(document.querySelector(".delete-filter")) !== "undefined"` is _always_ `true`

Comment: @Andreas that is not my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `.addEventListener()` instead of `.onclick`, and DOM traversal to find the container of the clicked button, you don't need `dltbtn`, `contbtn` or an index.

`this` in the event handler assigned with `.addEventListener()` is the clicked element -> the button.
With `.closest(".filter-solid")` we travel the DOM up to the first element that matches the selector `".filter-solid"` (in this case `.parentNode`) would do the same -> the container that should be removed.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".delete-filter")
  .forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      const container = this.closest(".filter-solid");
      if (container) {
        container.remove();
      }
    });
  })
```

```css
.filter-solid {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #faa938;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  margin: 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="filter-solid"><span> فقط کالاهای تخفیف دار </span> <button class="delete-filter"><i class="fa fa-times">X</i></button></span>
  <span class="filter-solid"><span> از <span>200,000</span> تا <span>1,200,000</span> تومان </span> <button class="delete-filter"><i class="fa fa-times">X</i></button></span>
  <span class="filter-solid"><span> رنگ آبی </span> <button class="delete-filter"><i class="fa fa-times">X</i></button></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a live collection. To quote the MDN page:

> **Warning:** This is a live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). Changes in the DOM will reflect in the array as the changes occur. If an element selected by this array no longer qualifies for the selector, it will automatically be removed. Be aware of this for iteration purposes.

Meaning that `contbtn[i].remove()` will implicitly remove the current element from the array (because it is removed from the DOM), shifting all elements that come after it.

An easy change would be swapping from `getElementsByClassName()` to [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which does not not return a live collection.

```js
let dltbtn = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-filter");
let contbtn = document.querySelectorAll(".filter-solid");
```

With this change elements in the resulting collection won't shift when `contbtn[i].remove()` is called.

---

Another good solution in this scenario would be to use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation). This means adding an event listener to the wrapping `<div>` which checks if the `.delete-filter` is clicked and removes the associated `.filter-solid`.

This also simplifies adding new elements, since you no longer need to add event listeners on those new elements.

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".filter-solid-container");

for (const container of containers) {
  container.addEventListener("click", function ({ target }) {
    // only search within the container by addeding the container selector
    const dlt = target.closest(".filter-solid-container, .delete-filter");
    
    // return if not clicked on .delete-filter
    // (`dlt` will be set to the container)
    if (dlt == container) return;
    
    // I assume that .filter-solid is always present around a .delete-filter
    // find and remove it
    dlt.closest(".filter-solid").remove();
  });
}

// demo: adding a new filter without fumbling with event handlers
const addFilter = document.querySelector("#add-filter");
addFilter.addEventListener("click", function () {
  containers[0].innerHTML += `
    <span class="filter-solid">
      <span>test</span>
      <button class="delete-filter"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    </span>
  `;
});
```

```css
.filter-solid {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #faa938;
  border-radius: 2vw;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  color: #525666;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.filter-solid button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: #525666;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-SfTiTlX6kk+qitfevl/7LibUOeJWlt9rbyDn92a1DqWOw9vWG2MFoays0sgObmWazO5BQPiFucnnEAjpAB+/Sw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">

<div class="filter-solid-container">
  <span class="filter-solid"><span> فقط کالاهای تخفیف دار </span> <button class="delete-filter"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></span>
  <span class="filter-solid"><span> از <span>200,000</span> تا <span>1,200,000</span> تومان </span> <button class="delete-filter"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></span>
  <span class="filter-solid"><span> رنگ آبی </span> <button class="delete-filter"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></span>
</div>

<button id="add-filter" type="button">add filter</button>
```